# can't submit multiple onChange AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I use this code to get value from `tahun` and `provinsi`, but why i still get error `Notice: Undefined index: provinsi` ?

If i remove `provinsi` from my code and use `tahun`, i can get data from my database.

```html
function myFunction() {
    var provinsi    = document.getElementById("provinsi").value;
    var tahun       = document.getElementById("tahun").value;
    console.log('provinsi id : '+ provinsi + ' dan tahun : '+tahun);
    $.ajax({
        type    : 'POST',
        url     : 'test2.php',
        data    : {
            tahun : tahun,
            id_provinsi : provinsi
        },
        success:function(html){
            $('#gini-rasio').html(html);
        }
    }); 

}
```

and this is my test2.php

```html
    <?php
include('db.php');

if(isset($_POST["tahun"]) && !empty($_POST["tahun"])){ 
    
    $query = $db->query("SELECT data_content FROM laporan_gini WHERE nama_tahun = ".$_POST['tahun']." && id_provinsi = ".$_POST['provinsi']." && nama_variabel_turunan = 'perkotaan'");

    $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
    
    if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            echo '<h1>'.$row['data_content'].'</h1> ';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<h1>error</h1>';
    }
}
?>
```

this is my full code in my [github](https://github.com/adeguntoro/tata_kota/blob/master/test/input.php)

Comment: Because `provinsi` and `id_provinsi` are not really the same thing …

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: `id_provinsi` should take the value of your `myFunction()`, but that function doesn't return anything

Comment: Okay, i edit my code, still i  can only show data from `tahun`. I put all `onChange` result in same function. Still, i can only show `tahun` data from my database.

Comment: In your `data` you're still  sending `id_provinsi` to the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after i check again, i think i made some mistake in here, i replace this

`if(isset($_POST["tahun"]) && !empty($_POST["tahun"])){`

with this

`if(isset($_POST["provinsi"]) && !empty($_POST["tahun"])){`